# Getting previous HABTM values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many, before-save, after-save

In my app, I have several `clients`, and they have several `elements`  (via `has_many_through` association) depending on a certain `BusinessType` to which `Client` belongs to so that instead of manually adding all the `elements` to the `Client`, I can just select the `BusinessType` and everything gets added automatically (`business_type` in `Client` is `attr_readonly`). `BusinessType` HABTM `elements`.

Here's the catch, after creation with the default `BusinessType`, the clients can update their elements and remove or add as they please (mostly add), so what I'm trying to do is the following:

Suppose one `business_type` has elements `[1,2,3]` and is assigned to one `client`, then, the following elements are added manually to the `client` = `[4,5,6]` so it ends up having `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, ok everything's fine here.

But after this, the `business_type` gets updated and has element `2` removed, so it ends up being `[1,3]`. Here's the deal, I want the client to be updated by removing the `2`, but not the `[4,5,6]` that do not correspond to the `business_type` in question so that it ends up `[1,3,4,5,6]`, I'm using an `after_update` callback to update the `clients'` elements but the `_was` method doesn't work for HABTM relationships (to get the old `business_type's` elements.

I've tried using a `before_update` callback to first to `client.elements = client.elements - business_type.elements` to store momentarily in the DB `[1,2,3,4,5,6] - [1,2,3] = [4,5,6]`, and in the after_update do `client.elements = client.elements + business_type.elements` to get `[4,5,6] + [1,3] = [1,3,4,5,6]`but this has already the new value of `[1,3]`. How can I get the old `business_type.elements` value in the `before_update` or `after_update`?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in an app, and the only solution I could come up with was to store the values before doing update_attributes in the controller.

Example code:

*Models*

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :join_table => "categories_products"

  def remember_prev_values(values)
    @prev_values = values
  end

  def before_update_do_something
    puts @prev_values - self.category_ids # Any categories removed?
    puts self.category_ids - @prev_values # Any categories added?
  end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products, :join_table => "categories_products"
end
```

In the update method in the products controller I do the following:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def update
    @product.remember_prev_values(@product.category_ids)
    if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
      flash[:notice] = "Product was successfully updated."
      redirect_to(product_path(@product))
    else
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

It is not ideal, but it is then possible to "catch" the habtm inserts/removes before they are executed.

I do think it is possible to do in a callback, but you might need to "hack" into ActiveRecord.

I did not spend much time on trying to dig into ActiveRecord internals, as this is a simple implementation that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use after_initialize callback to store previous values.

```
after_initialize do @previous_elements = elements.map{|x| x} end
```

Note that here we make a copy of assosiations by map function call.